# Testing google places api without credit card

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am building an angular project. The customer basically should provide an address. I want to use google places API, but don't have any credit card and google won't let me activate my API key. I want to know if there is some way I could test google API on the localhost.

Thank in advance for your answers.

Comment: API key and billing account are mandatory.

Comment: To add to Xomena's comment, you don't need a credit card specifically. Google accepts other payment methods such as debit card, bank account, paypal... it depends on the country too. Check out this doc https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods

Comment: For basic functionality, don't use a key.